# Icono de FA aparece sin tamaño

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con el cual llevo un buen rato borrando, comentando y editando cosas al azar para ver si logro darle tamaño a los iconos de FA ya que no encuentro manera.

Tengo por ejemplo este elemento de una lista `<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>` en el cual se supone que el icono de una casa debería aparecer a las izquierda del texto pero al inspeccionar con F12 me lo indica de la siguiente manera y proporciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que los iconos FA son texto por lo que deberia usar `font-size:` y lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
.container nav ul li{
font-size: 25px;
}
```

¿Por lo que se supone que tanto el texto *HOME* como el icono deberían tener dicho tamaño, no?
¿A qué se puede deber esto? ¿Puede alguna otra propiedad alterar el tamaño del icono?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Integrante la librería de estilos (css, js) de la tipografía??

Answer (score 0):

Si el icono no te aparece es porque no integrastes correctamente FontAwesome a tu proyecto. Después de descargar y descomprimir el archivo; en la carpeta css copia el archivo all.css e insertalo dentro de la etiqueta "head" asi:

Nota: puedes renombrar el archivo a fontawesome.css

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fontawesome.css" type="text/css">
```

Luego copia la carpeta "webfonts" a la raíz de tu proyecto. con estos sencillos pasos podrás hacer que aparezca tu icono y cambiarle el tamaño como los indicas arriba.

¡importante! si movistes las fuentes a otra carpeta debes ir al final del archivo css y cambiar la ruta en el @font-face

```
src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
```